# ValueError: There may be at most 1 To headers in a message

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I am trying to write a very basic email sending script. Here is my code ..

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content("Test message.")
msg['Subject'] = "Test Subject!!!"
msg['From'] = "myemail@gmail.com"

email_list = ["xyz@gmail.com", "abc@gmail.com"]

for email in email_list:
    msg['To'] = email
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword")
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
```

the script should send mail to multiple recipients so, I need to change the `msg['To']` field when iterating through loop But I get the following error in traceback bellow.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exp.py", line 66, in <module>
    msg['To'] = email
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/message.py", line 407, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError("There may be at most {} {} headers "
ValueError: There may be at most 1 To headers in a message
```

How do I solve ? Please help. Thank you..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clean the 'To' property of the message.

```
for email in email_list:
    msg['To'] = email
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword")
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
    del msg['To]
```

Below is the code that throws the exception: (\Python385\Lib\email\message.py)

```
def __setitem__(self, name, val):
    """Set the value of a header.

    Note: this does not overwrite an existing header with the same field
    name.  Use __delitem__() first to delete any existing headers.
    """
    max_count = self.policy.header_max_count(name)
    if max_count:
        lname = name.lower()
        found = 0
        for k, v in self._headers:
            if k.lower() == lname:
                found += 1
                if found >= max_count:
                    raise ValueError("There may be at most {} {} headers "
                                     "in a message".format(max_count, name))
    self._headers.append(self.policy.header_store_parse(name, val))
```

Answer (score 4):

Not knowing the inner working of the EmailMessage class, what I can assume is that every call to `__setitem__` writes to the head of the email message, so by calling it in a loop, the header is being written multiple times, what I'd recommend is that you make an email message for every email you'll send, but create only one server:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
server.starttls()
server.login("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword")
email_list = ["xyz@gmail.com", "abc@gmail.com"]
for email in email_list:
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content("Test message.")
    msg['Subject'] = "Test Subject!!!"
    msg['From'] = "myemail@gmail.com"
    msg['To'] = email
    server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

Only if you need for the messages to be sent **separately**. If you want to send the same message to everyone at the same time you could do something like

```
msg['To'] = ', '.join(email_list)
```

Comment: If you want to include the recipient names, not just the addresses, then it becomes difficult. You must encode the list propertly. There is email.utils.formataddr but that can only format a simple name+address pair. AFAIK there is no util method to encode a list of name+address pairs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of addresses, and some of them include a name/title, then I think this is the correct way to do it. Please note that parseaddr + formataddr pair may not be needed, but parseaddr can correct some malformed recipients.

```
from email.header import Charset
from email.message import EmailMessage, MIMEPart
from email.utils import formataddr, parseaddr

test_recipients = [
        "Mr. John Doe <johndoe@example.com>",
        "Mr. Jane Doe <janedoe@example.com>",
        "somebody@example.com"
]
to_header= []
for raw_address in (test_recipients):
    # Parse and recreate
    title, email = parseaddr(raw_address)
    if title and email:
        to_header.append(f"{title} <{email}>")
    elif email:
        to_header.append(email)
# Encode after join
message.add_header("To", Charset("utf-8").header_encode(", ".join(to_header)))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just delete
server.quit() from loop
and add
del msg['to']
then there is no error

Answer (score 0):

```
# original code
for email in email_list:
    msg['To'] = email
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword")
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
```

Replacing "`server.quit`" with "`def msg['to']` is how I got it to work!

```
# new code
for email in email_list:
    msg['To'] = email
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword")
    server.send_message(msg)
    del msg['To']
```